# strripos does not seems to work for me

Tags: strpos

I'm trying to use strripos in fact I try to add a parameter to an URL fro translating my website,

the fact is that not over the url requested does have a parameter so I can not to everytime `&lang=en` but I need to do `?lang=en`

I've tried to do a function using `strripos` like that

```
/**
 * Fonction qui renvoit le bon caractère en tant que paramètre
 * @param type $string
 * @return string
 */
function checkParam($string){
    $lookfor = "?";
    $position = strripos($string, $lookfor);
    if($position === true){
    return "&";
    }else{
    return "?";
    }
}
```

I have for example that url : `$url_courante = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

which give me something like that

```
www.mydomain.eu/index.php?p=nos-produits
```

but it does not recognize the  `?` in that string, so it returns always to me false and I can not set properly my lang to the url.

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Dunno exactly what your goal is but change it to "if( $position !== false )". The function returns false when a needle does not exists. I don't want to be rude but when I look at your question, you have to practice your English and your PHP skills. Bye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strripos` returns an integer or `false`, not `true`. Switch the condition around and check for `false`.

```
function checkParam($string){
    $lookfor = "?";
    $position = strripos($string, $lookfor);
    if($position === false){
        return "?";
    }else{
        return "&";
    }
}
```

Also, there is no need for `strripos` because you are only checking to see if the string exists. It does not matter if you find the first or last. Case is not an issue when you are searching for a question mark, either. I would use `strpos` instead.